# How to get rid of the bottom border of the React Native Paper TextInput when focused

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, react-native, expo

I'm using `react-native` with `react-native-paper`.

I have the following code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Button, TextInput } from 'react-native-paper';

export default class Header extends Component {

  state = {
    text: '',
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput value={this.state.text} style={styles.input} />
        <Button mode="contained" style={styles.button}>Add Todo</Button>
      </View>
    );
  }

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    height: 40,
  },
  input: {
    flex: 1,
    height: 40,
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  button: {
    flex: 0,
    height: 40,
    justifyContent: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#54c084",
  },
});
```

which outputs something like this:

[image]

then, when the input gets the focus it is like this:

[image]

I need to get rid of the bottom border on the `TextInput`.

Any idea on how to do that?

**EDIT 01**

Interesting, if I do:

```
<TextInput value={this.state.text} style={styles.input} theme={{ colors: {primary: "#f00"} }} />
```

then, I get the following output:

[image]

but I just want to modify the color of the bottom border, and keep untouched the color of the caret.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have set the `underlineColor` prop to `transparent`

```
<TextInput 
  value={this.state.text}
  style={styles.input}
  underlineColor="transparent"   // add this
/>
```

## EDIT

> This is an issue in `react-native-paper`. You can not change active text input underline color. https://github.com/callstack/react-native-paper/issues/688.
>   However, if you want to change unfocused text input underline color you can user above code

Comment: this works partially, it removes the bottom border when the input doesn't have the focus (first image) but keeps the bottom border when the input gets the focus (second image, exactly the same)

Answer (score 6):

Possible solution is

```
const theme = useTheme();
const { colors } = theme;

...

<TextInput
  underlineColor="transparent"
  theme={{...theme, colors: {...colors, primary: 'transparent'}}}
/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Set underline color to transparent.

--- Edit ---

You can set underline color by setting transparent to prop `underlineColor`.

```
  <TextInput
    underlineColor={"transparent"}
  />
```

Comment: Why should one do that, and how?

Comment: this works partially, it removes the bottom border when the input doesn't have the focus (first image) but keeps the bottom border when the input gets the focus (second image, exactly the same)

Answer (score 2):

**To change the Underline and Label color when focused, you need to pass the props theme, like this:**

```
theme={{colors: {text: 'black', primary: 'rgb(23, 157, 227)'}}}
```

- **Text** is to change the values that you put in the input
- **Primary** is to  change the underline and the label color

Comment: giving primary: 'transparent' removes the underline color when focused

Answer (score 1):

as [Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput) describe:

> TextInput has by default a border at the bottom of its view. This border has its padding set by the background image provided by the system, and it cannot be changed. Solutions to avoid this is to either not set height explicitly, case in which the system will take care of displaying the border in the correct position, or to not display the border by setting underlineColorAndroid to transparent

so you can simply use [underlineColorAndroid](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#underlinecolorandroid) props:

```
<TextInput 
  value={this.state.text}
  style={styles.input}
  underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
/>
```

Comment: can you give a try of [react-native-paper TextInput.js](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-paper/blob/master/src/components/TextInput.js#L187) and give hardcoded `underlineColorAndroid`?